# Delete repeated headings using macros

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to find a word macro that can delete both repeated headings as well as headings with no content.  For example, with the following headers

```
3.2.3 Run ID : 795 - REG - C1 - TC003 Popup window not working
3.2.4 Run ID : 796 - REG - C1 - TC004 Search
3.2.5 Run ID : 879 - REG - C1 - TC005 Blabla
3.2.6 Run ID : 797 - REG - C1 - TC005 Blabla
3.2.7 Run ID : 799 - REG - C1 - TC006 ReplyTo functionality
```

I would like to delete the two repeated ones (`TC005 Blabla`)

Comment: Unless it's a question which has already  been asked and answered, this is not a place for "finding" a macro: typically here you would post code you're having a problem with and get help fixing it.

Comment: this is my code. i could not find common search "text"..

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub lösch_kapitel()
Dim fundbereich As Range
Dim firstRound As Boolean
Dim counter As Integer

firstRound = True
counter = 0

Set fundbereich = ThisDocument.Content 'gesamtes aktives Dokument durchsuchen

    With fundbereich.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Format = True
        .Style = "Überschrift 4"
        .Text = "TC??????????????"
        .Forward = True
        .MatchCase = True
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop 'nach jeder Fundstelle stoppen

        Do While fundbereich.Find.Execute = True 'wenn eine Überschrift1 gefunden wird

               If firstRound = True Then

                 pFound = fundbereich.Text
               ElseIf (firstRound = False) Then

                    If fundbereich.Text = pFound Then
                        fundbereich.Select 'gefundene Überschrift auswählen
                         'alles von der Überschrift bis zur nächsten der gleichen Ebene auswählen:
                        ThisDocument.Bookmarks("\headinglevel").Select
                        Selection.Delete
                        counter = counter + 1
                    End If
                    pFound = fundbereich.Text
               End If
               firstRound = False

        Loop

        MsgBox counter & " Kapitel gelöscht!"

    End With

ThisDocument.TablesOfContents(1).Update

End Sub
```

Comment: The number of the characters after "TC.." is sometimes different.. How could i check it dynamically?